# Delay in IAP availability

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

InApp  purchase are not available after 10 hours of launch of my new App , has some one else faced same issue ?

How long does it take to propagate through the Apple servers ?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah the first time I launched mine they took ages, can't remember exactly how long. Was more than 8 hours though.

Comment: thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

In App purchases are available on the App Store now , took around 24 hours after approval :-)